# If else statement involving two numbers in scientific notation

Tags: shell-script, floating-point

I have two numbers in scientific notation and I want to do some comparison between them in an if statement in bash. While doing so, I am getting error like bwlow:
E.g:

```
bash-4.2$ a=10e-12
bash-4.2$ b=12e-12
bash-4.2$ if (( a > b )); then r=1; else r=0; fi
bash: ((: 10e: value too great for base (error token is "10e")
```

The same problem doesn't arise if a and b are integers. I see problem with floating numbers to if I use the above statement.
Is there a simple way by which I can do the comparison within if statement?

Comment: bash doesn't do floats (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541568/how-to-do-float-comparison-in-bash) and "bc" doesn't do scientific notation.  so you're looking at awk or perl or ...?

Answer (score 1):

### Using "awk"

As @Theophrastus has noted above, neither `bash` nor `bc` support scientific notation.

For simple comparisons and calculations, I suggest using `awk` (which does handle xEy numbers):

```
a=10e-12
b=12e-12

r=$(awk 'BEGIN{print ('$a'>'$b')?1:0}')
echo $r
```

For more complex expressions, you can avoid the cumbersome quote handling and escaping by passing the variables to `awk` with `-v`, which would actually be the preferred way to do it:

```
r=$(awk -v a="$a" -v b="$b" 'BEGIN{print (a<b)?1:0}')
```

### Using "bc"

There are ways to reformat your notation to the alternative form *x * 10^y* which is understood by `bc` (or you could just do it yourself), however `bc` has some pecularities when it comes to negative exponents (as in your example):

```
$ bc
10^12
1000000000000
10^-12
0
```